# Run PhantomJS and Chrome browser on the same Selenium grid node

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a Selenium grid cluster includes 1 hub and multiple nodes. I want to run on all nodes multiple instances of Chrome and multiple instances of PhantomJS.

**I have the following config file for the node:**

```
    {
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "phantomjs",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

**To run the node, I use:**

```
java -Dphantomjs.binary.path="ghostdriver" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node -hub http://{myIp}:4444/grid/register/ -nodeConfig "/Users/myUser/Desktop/selenium/nodeConfig.json"
```

**I'm connecting to Chrome remote driver successfully:**

```
String hubURL = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), capabilities);
```

However, when trying to connect to PhantomJS remote driver, **I still get Chrome browser with chrome capabilities**:

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.PHANTOMJS);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.MAC);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), capabilities);
```

From the grid console I can see that all browsers are available (including PhantomJS) [grid console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmVEN.png)

What am I doing wrong??

**EDIT:**

Issue is that PhantomJS is supported until Selenium server version 3.7.1

Comment: found this on node startup: 14:37:48.396 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver

Comment: Found that on selenium standalone server version 3.8.1 there is no PhantomJSDriver in classpath. with version 3.7.1 everything is working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have defined the `capabilities` for **`PhantomJS`** as follows ;

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.PHANTOMJS);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.MAC);
```

But I don't see those `capabilities` being passed when `new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), capabilities);` is invoked as **`DesiredCapabilities capabilities`** is defined at a later stage. Can you try this code block :

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.PHANTOMJS);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.MAC);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), capabilities);
```

Comment: I accidentally copied the code in the wrong order. The issue was with the version of selenium grid standalone server jar. looks like they have a bug on version 3.8.1 and 3.8.0 for PhantomJSDriver